# How to take the widget key(org.sonar.api.web.WidgetProperty) in a variable in java

Tags: widget

How to take the widget key in a variable in java..
Widget is created using org.sonar.api.web.WidgetProperty.. 
code is :

```
@UserRole(UserRole.USER)@Description("Show how to use Ruby Widget API")@WidgetCategory("Sample")@WidgetProperties({@WidgetProperty(key = "Repository Name",
    description = "Like git,svn or clearcase",
    optional = false), @WidgetProperty(key = "User Story Number",
    description = "If multiple userStories then please seperate them by    comma(,)",
    optional = false), @WidgetProperty(key = "SRC/Code Location",
    optional = false)
})
```

I want to access the key "Repository Name" in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it's not possible. Widget properties have been designed in order to customize dashboards, not to configure project analysis. You should use standard mechanism in order to extend and use project/global settings.

-- Answer taken from

http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-Get-the-value-from-a-widget-property-into-a-sensor-class-td4525982.html